# Angular 2 call API on init

Tags: angular

I have a service in angular that I a trying to call an api to get user data based on localStorage ID. For some reason the API is not even getting called. Can someone help please? I am calling the getUser() function in the constructor...

Here is my code:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }      from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import {Subject} from "../../node_modules/rxjs/src/Subject";
import {Observable} from "../../node_modules/rxjs/src/Observable";
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";


@Injectable()
export class UserService{

  userData:any;
  user:Subject<any>;
  user$:Observable<any>;
  loggedIn = new Subject<boolean>();
  loggedIn$:Observable<any>;


  constructor(private http:Http, public authService:AuthService, public router:Router) {

    this.user = new Subject();
    this.user$ = this.user.asObservable();
    this.loggedIn = new Subject();
    this.loggedIn$ = this.loggedIn.asObservable();
    this.getUser().subscribe();




  }

  getUser(){

if(localStorage['_id'] && localStorage['jwt']){

  let headers = new Headers();
  //headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  headers.append('x-access-token', localStorage['jwt']);
  console.log('We have a user ID! Lets try to get a user!');
  return this.http
    .get('/api/accounts/' + localStorage['_id'], {headers : headers} )
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map((res) => {
      return res;
    }, (error) => console.log('There was an error', error));
}
```

}

```
  }

  createAccount(user) {
    user.assessment = {

      1: {id: "1", answer: "", subs: []},
      2: {id: "2", answer: "", subs: []},
      3: {id: "3", answer: "", subs: []},
      4: {id: "4", answer: "", subs: []},
      5: {id: "5", answer: "", subs: []},
      6: {id: "6", answer: "", subs: []},
      7: {id: "7", answer: "", subs: []},
      8: {id: "8", answer: "", subs: []},
      9: {id: "9", answer: "", subs: []},
      10: {id: "10", answer: "", subs: []},
      11: {id: "11", answer: "", subs: []},
      12: {id: "12", answer: "", subs: []},
      13: {id: "13", answer: "", subs: []},
      14: {id: "14", answer: "", subs: []},
      15: {id: "15", answer: "", subs: []}

    };
    console.log('Attempting to create an account with', user);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http
      .post(
        '/api/accounts',
        JSON.stringify(user),
        {headers}
      )
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map((res) => {
        if (res['account']) {
          this.loggedIn.next(true);
          this.userData = res["account"];
          //this.user$ = res;
          //this.user.next('test');
          return res;
        }
      });
  }

  login(user) {

    console.log('Loggin you in...');
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http
      .post(
        '/api/authenticate',
        JSON.stringify(user),
        {headers}
      )
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map((res) => {
        console.log('Login Result:', res);

          localStorage.setItem('jwt', res.token);
          localStorage.setItem('_id', res.user[0]._id);
          //set user service info...
          this.loggedIn.next(true);
          this.userData = res.user[0];
          this.user.next(res.user[0]);
          return res;
      });
  }


  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
    this.loggedIn.next(false);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observables don't do anything without `.subscribe(...)` or `.toPromise()`.

Either you do it directly inside `getUser()` like

```
 getUser(){

    if(localStorage['_id'] && localStorage['jwt']){

      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      console.log('We have a user ID! Lets try to get a user!');
      this.http
        .get('/api/accounts/' + localStorage['_id'], {headers} )
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe((res) => {
          console.log('User restrieved!', res);
        }, (error) => console.log('There was an error', error));
    }
}
```

or where you call it

```
  constructor(private http:Http, public authService:AuthService, public router:Router) {

    this.user = new Subject();
    this.user$ = this.user.asObservable();
    this.loggedIn = new Subject();
    this.loggedIn$ = this.loggedIn.asObservable();
    this.getUser().subscribe();
  }
```

You probably also want to do something with the received user info. Currently there is nothing happening with the received data except being printed to the console.

Comment: I seem to be having a problem where the headers are not getting added to the .get request? Im getting a "toString" parse error

Comment: ` {headers}` should be ` {headers: headers}`

Comment: Tried that. No luck... here is the URL so you can see the error. http://tfl.judsondesigns.com

Comment: The link seems not to work for me. I see only "Loading ..." on an otherwise entirely white page.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer with es6 you can write '{headers}' instead of '{headers: headers}' if your variable has the same name as the object property you're setting.

Comment: Here is my new component. getUser(){

    if(localStorage['_id'] && localStorage['jwt']){

      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      console.log('We have a user ID! Lets try to get a user!');
      return this.http
        .get('/api/accounts/' + localStorage['_id'], {headers : headers} )
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map((res) => {
          return res;
        }, (error) => console.log('There was an error', error));
    }
  } ///////////Refersh the page while console open

Comment: Ouch. Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: This was the issue: headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); Apparently there is a UMD bug. Thanks for your help. I will update my code.